# Error: "The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract"?

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer, iserializable

I have a class Foo marked `[Serializable]` and implementing `ISerializable`. I'm trying to serialize it via DataContractSerializer. In GetObjectData I do this:

```
info.AddValue("Test", new[] { 1,2,3});
```

It fails with:

> Element ':Test' contains data of the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfint' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfint' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I tried passing a `knownTypes` arg to the DataContractSerializer constructor - didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a `knownTypes` arg to the DataContractSerializer constructor will *not* help. Instead, add `[KnownType(typeof(int[]))]` to class Foo itself.